# HTML5 Required attribute not enforced on FormObject.submit()

Tags: asp.net, forms, html, submit, required

HTML5 makes it easy to enforce an input to have a value: wow! This would be great in a .NET web application. I made a quick implementation of this and noticed something interesting. My newly-required input field was enforced on submit button click, and on-enter from a form control that uses the browser's enter-submits-the-form functionality. My newly-required input is not enforced when a control calls __doPostback (which, eventually calls form.submit()).

Well that's not right! What's up Firefox?! But, that's how it works in Chrome, so either that's a coincidence that they're both wrong or they're not both wrong.

So can anyone tell me why that makes sense? It seems this neat attribute could never be used in .NET web applications, because it's only other method to submit a form is to call __doPostback when the browser doesn't handle it, which causes the required validation to only happen sometimes. But other times this makes sense, such as when a link is set up to post back to the form before navigating the user to another page: we wouldn't want the user to get stuck when they think they're just navigating away.

Answer (score 2):

I can't tell you, why this makes sense, but FF and Chrome are right about this behavior. If you want to get this validated you have to trigger a submit button click.

There is also another strange thing about html5 validation: The checkValidity method does not invoke the native validation ui (in Opera it does, but this is a spec violation), although, it triggers the invalid event. It really would be a great thing to have programmatic API to get the validation ui shown, but the only way a user can see it is through interactive validation.

Comment: The fact that it's only displayed through clicking the submit button and that there's no programmatic API to trigger the validation UI makes this required attribute seem very broken and unappealing. But thanks! If my reputation wasn't so small I'd 'up' your post.